# Where is a fuel filter located on Astra H (2008) Z18XER gasoline injector?

Tags: astra, fuel-filter

Help me to find the location of a fuel filter on Astra H 2008 wagon (engine Z18XER).

Is it the same as on Cruse 2009 F18D4?

Astra known as a model of many brands like Opel, Holden, Vauxhall. It is all General Motors. Same as Cruze, mostly known as Chevrolet, but also Holden and others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically there are two fuel filters. Attention: I suspect the fuel system to be country specific (depending on the fuel quality). This answer describes the european version of the fuel system (to be exactly fuel quality EN228)

- The coarse filter in the fuel tank, including the pump. You need to open the fuel tank from under the rear seats. Pump the tank empty before opening the tank. The filter element is not replacable, you need to replace the entire "in tank module".
- The "activated carbon canister": Remove the right front wheel and the inner rear protective housing to access the filter element. Disconnect the quick-connect couplings of the vent line in the engine compartement behind the right strut bearing

Comment: Thank you. So there is no stand alone filter that can be replaced separately, without the pump. If it is so, please add this to your answer in straight and clear way. Thank you.